# Bundle Transformer in ASP.NET Web Application (NOT MVC)

Tags: asp.net, web, obfuscation, minify, bundletransformer

I would like to minify and obfuscate javascript files of my Web Application (not MVC). I based my code on this simple configuration: https://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/discussions/541419, but 
it seems to have no effect on js files when viewed from the browser. I did not understand if Bundle Transformer is only applicable to MVC Web Applications. I installed BundleTransformer.Core, BundleTransformer.Yui, Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.

Global.asax.cs:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        var nullOrderer = new NullOrderer();
        var scriptBundle = new CustomScriptBundle("~/jscbundle/");
        scriptBundle.Include("~/js/main.js");
        scriptBundle.IncludeDirectory("~/js/", "*.js", true);
        scriptBundle.Orderer = nullOrderer;
        bundles.Add(scriptBundle);
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
    }
}

protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

Web.Config:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
  ...
</system.web>

<bundleTransformer xmlns="http://tempuri.org/BundleTransformer.Configuration.xsd">
  <core>
    <css>
      <minifiers>
        <add name="NullMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Minifiers.NullMinifier, BundleTransformer.Core" />
        <add name="YuiCssMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.Yui.Minifiers.YuiCssMinifier, BundleTransformer.Yui" />
      </minifiers>
      <translators>
        <add name="NullTranslator" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Translators.NullTranslator, BundleTransformer.Core" enabled="false" />
      </translators>
    </css>
    <js defaultMinifier="YuiJsMinifier">
      <minifiers>
        <add name="NullMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Minifiers.NullMinifier, BundleTransformer.Core" />
        <add name="YuiJsMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.Yui.Minifiers.YuiJsMinifier, BundleTransformer.Yui" />
      </minifiers>
      <translators>
        <add name="NullTranslator" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Translators.NullTranslator, BundleTransformer.Core" enabled="false" />
      </translators>
    </js>
  </core>
</bundleTransformer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bundle and Minify comes by default in  normal Asp.net project in VS2015 onwards.

Minify is  not restricted to MVC, we can use it for any files.
In Android  , we can obfuscate  the complete project.

Please let me know which version of VS are you using ? so i can provide assistance accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read the Rick Anderson's posts about using of Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework with [Web Forms](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/08/14/adding-bundling-and-minification-to-web-forms.aspx) and [Web Pages](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/08/15/adding-web-optimization-to-a-web-pages-site.aspx).